# Can I update my navigation property in unit of work repository pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, unit-of-work

I have two Entities in my project :

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }      
    public virtual B B { get; set; }
}


public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> LastAliveTime { get; set; }      
    public virtual ICollection<A> A { get; set; }
}
```

I am using unit of work repository pattern with Entity Framework and I do the following :

```
stirng id = "abc";
var aService = unitOfWork.GetRepository<A>();
var ins = aService.FindBy(a => a.Id == id);
```

I know that it is OK to update **ins** and save the **dbcontext**.

What I need to know is :

```
ins.B.LastAliveTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Will this work always?

Is it the right way of updating the  LastAliveTime of B entity or should I initialize another repository like below ?

```
var bService = unitOfWork.GetRepository<B>();
```

Comment: Why at all would you have repository per entity type?

Comment: Assuming `virtual` means lazy-loading, it depends on underlying context lifetime. If context is still alive, when you call `ins.B`, or `ins.B` is already loaded, it will work. Otherwise you'll get `InvalidOperationException`, attempting to load `B` when context is disposed.

Answer (score 1):

You **don't need to do** that.

Either you have to use eager loading (`Include(x=>x.B)`) or lazy loading. Then you'll not have any issues.

Comment: I need to do a minimal fix on an existing project and as @Dennis mentioned, as of now the code is working if my context is not disposed, which will do for now.

Comment: This will not work if the virtual property that needs to be updated is a ICollection.